# Push information from Django to iOS locally

Tags: python, ios, django, sockets, push

Is it possible to push information from `Django` to an `iOS` application over a local intranet? Whenever there is a specific `POST` request to the `Django`-server, I would like to either push out some information to the devices, or just send a signal to the devices, asking them to pull from the `API`.

This problem would normally be solved using `push notifications`, but the fact is that all the devices including the server are only connected to a local network without internet connection.

I have been thinking of using some kind of a `socket`, but haven't been able to find something that suits this purpose, and writing my own would be a lot of work and probably not worth it.

Does anyone know of any frameworks that can help, or have another approach to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Once your app is no longer in the foreground, the only way to communicate with it at all is via push notification.

If the app is open, you could create some kind of listener socket, register it with your Django server, and have the server talk to the socket.  Otherwise your best bet would be to just poll the server every minute or two.

Comment: I figured that actually, bad idea not to specify. It only needs to work in the foreground, and it's very important that it gets realtime information without polling every time something changes. Would you mind pointing me in a direction of a Django-socket implementation?

Comment: Sorry, I don't do python or Django, only iOS.